# Idiomatic Django conditional filter queryset

Tags: python, django

I am sharing a viewset between two types of routes in Django: one is a nested route (`/users/:id/comments/:id/`), and a regular route (`/comments/:id/`). The query set returned is either filtered by the `user_pk` or it's not. What is an idiomatic way of writing the following?

```
if(user_pk):
    queryset = Comment.objects.filter(pk=pk, user=user_pk)
else:
    queryset = Comment.objects.filter(pk=pk)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine.
As [this function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#filter) doesn't have a default value for parameters,
you would have to use a dictionary if you want to make it more DRY.
I'd do something like:

```
kwargs = {
    'pk': pk,
    'user': user_pk
}
if not kwargs['user']:
    del kwargs['user']
queryset = Comment.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```